# Can you use a Blod Stone to find a relative?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

One of my players has a missing sister. I am wondering if he could create a Blod Stone (from Storm King's Thunder) with his own blood to locate her. Would he be able to? Or would the Blod Stone just locate himself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

He would be able to, given a little GM fiat.

From the item description:

> While
>   the item is on your person, you can use your action to divine
>   the location of the creature nearest to you that is related
>   to the blood in the item and that isn't undead. You
>   sense the distance and direction of the creature relative
>   to your location. The creature is either the one whose
>   blood is in the item or a blood relative.

It further mentions that such stones are given as gifts to siblings or from parents to children- the non-genocidal uses imply heavily that when the description refers to "the creature nearest to you," that creature won't be *you*.

That said, other than blood, a 5,000 gp diamond, and references to a ritual, there's no written method of making a *blod stone*, so you'll have to come up with one.